# setInverval cannot find function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla, mootools

I dumbed down this script so it wasn't so bulky, but the gist of it is that I keep getting a reference error every second that I have no function getList(). I tried to move setInverval() above and below it but it pretty much does nothing. It tells me an anonymous function is calling getList and that it is not defined.

If it makes a difference I had to add the jquery conflict so that it didn't interfere with mootools and I'm running joomla 1.5

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
function getList(){
i=0;
$.getJSON(
    "./test.php",
    function(data) 
    {   
        while(data.streams[i]){
            channel[i] = data.streams[i];
            stats[i] = data.status[i];
            title[i] = data.title[i];
            viewers[i] = data.viewers[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
  );
}
setInterval("getList()", 1000);
});
```

I tried debugging it via console, but I'm still new at console debugging so it didn't get me too far. This program works alone, without joomla and the jquery no conflict stuff, in it's on HTML file just fine so I'm not sure what could possibly be wrong :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the eval-style version of `setInterval()` (by passing a string) the function must be global. This is a bad thing anyway, so do this instead:

```
setInterval(getList, 1000);
```

And so you never pass a string again, in case you need arguments, do it like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    getList(whatever, ...);
    // you can have more code here and even access local variables
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yeah that was my problem. ^.^ Ty

Answer (score 3):

```
setInterval(getList, 1000);
```

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) (as well as [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)) require a reference to a function. [Passing the function as strings have the same risk as using `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Passing_string_literals)

> Passing a string instead of a function to setTimeout() suffers from the same hazards as using eval. String literals are evaluated in the global context, so local symbols in the context where setTimeout() was called will not be available when the string is evaluated as code.